# How to automatically set marks on all of the edited lines?

Tags: mark, mark-ring

I would like to automatically set marks on all of the edited lines so that I can go back to any of my previous edited lines using `helm-mark-ring`.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but there are packages like `goto-chg` that allow you to jump back to the points in the buffer where an edit was made. (This works off undo information rather than modifying the mark ring.)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  `goto-chg` looks good.  It would be even better if we can use helm/ivy on top of it.  I searched for "helm-chg", but I could not find any interesting result.  Please let me know if you know any similar packages.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a built-in package `hilit-chg` which tracks and highlights the changes applied to a buffer.
I disable its highlight and but just use as a change-tracker.

The mode automatically put text-properties to mark the modified regions of a buffer, so I implement an anything (precedent of `helm`) source for myself, that collects the regions marked by `hilit-chg`.

https://gist.github.com/zk-phi/78fbfc612bd78abbab21909e2ab5fd10

I'm not familiar with `helm`, but I expect `helm` can also do something similar.