# Implement vim's Ctrl-O and Ctrl-I in emacs

Tags: vim-emulation, mark-ring

I find this to be a great feature from vim, and I miss it.

I've looked around, and it seems that one can add the current position to some mark ring, and then come back. But that's explicit. I need to know ahead that I'll need to remember where I am, add it to the ring, and move. Normally, I don't know I'll need this until it's too late.

How could this be implemented?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what `C-o` and `C-i` do in Vim, but what you describe is very similar to `C-u SPC` in Emacs. Did you try that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically set marks on all of the edited lines?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26447/how-to-automatically-set-marks-on-all-of-the-edited-lines)

Comment: @wvxvw: Seems like what he's looking for is automatically adding certain positions to the `mark-ring`, as opposed to having to explicitly do so ahead of time. That's addressed in the duplicate question.

Comment: @wvxvw: Yeah, that's precisely what I meant when I said "one can add the current position to some mark ring". Drew is right here. I'll see if the duplicate he found implements everything I want.